# Disable ispell when using Tramp

Tags: spacemacs, tramp, ispell

In my Spacemacs, I enabled the `spell-checking` layer which enables `ispell`. I noticed that my Tramp connection is very slow, and after debugging, I found that one of the causes is `ispell`:

```
02:07:20.446250 tramp-do-file-attributes-with-stat (5) # file attributes with stat: /path/to/.ispell_words
....
....
....
....
02:07:23.961344 tramp-send-command (6) # test -r /path/to/.ispell_default 2>/dev/null; echo tramp_exit_status $?
```

So about 3 seconds are wasted on `ispell`. I tried disabling the `spell-checking` layer and found that Tramp is indeed faster.

However, I don't want to totally disable `spell-checking`, as I in fact use it frequently when editing locally. Is it possible to disable `ispell` only when I use Tramp? Thanks!

Comment: The problem with your proposed solution is that there may be several buffers where `flyspell` is active (running `aspell` or other equivalent), so you are potentially dealing with several buffers at issue.  I encountered problems when running `flyspell` (i.e., an `aspell` running process) and other programs, although not necessarily tramp.  I ended up modifying the `flyspell` / `ispell` lisp libraries to turn on/off after the words have been checked in the current command loop.  The disadvantage with my solution is that re-reading custom words, depending on the length of the list, could slow..

Comment: I'm looking for a similar option: Disable Trump when using Ispell. Also when not using Ispell. ;-)  Sorry; couldn't resist.

Comment: @Drew and user25410:  Here is a link to the bug report that I opened (and was subsequently closed) about a year ago requesting that users be given the choice to prevent `aspell` (or `hunspell`) from running all the time; e.g., to run only when checking a word during the current command loop and then disengage:  https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=32610  Eli Z. opined that this was not desirable by most users and he stated a few reasons.  I did not, however, advise Eli Z. of problems that I experienced when other programs were active as a running process.  [I hacked my own on/off ...]